# Inline-block mistery: same code, same client, different server but space disappear

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a very strage problem with my template based on Bootstrap 3. I cannot past the code here because the problem is on a beta server protected and I cannot replicate it anywhere.

I have some problem with the inline-block property: In my production server I don't have any space between elements with display: inline-block property.

Same code, same client, same computer: only the server is different and one server "eat" the space between elements.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Probably because 1 server has a mimification process that gets ride of the white space(s) and the other server does not have this process.

Read here http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Try this

```
<element>...</element><element>...</element>
```

instead of this

```
<element>...</element>
<element>...</element>
```

In your source code and see if it makes a difference

if you want better readability you can also do

```
<element>
    ...
</element><element>
    ...
</element>
```

if you cannot change the source code, then set the inline-block element's PARENT to

```
font-size: 0;
```

and set the font-size of the inline-inline-block elements to the appropriate font size. This is considered a hack and should be avoided if the source code can be edited

Comment: no so easy with haml :/

Comment: what is haml? Anyway, that's most likely the issue, you can fix this using css as well but it is considered a hack

Comment: haml is HTML Abstraction Markup Language, I use it to create HTML templates.

Comment: Ok well I can show you the css hack way if you want